# cloning a tcp/ip packet with python

Tags: python, sockets, ethernet, tcp

I have captured some packages with wireshark and i want to resend them with my own software, written in python. I am using socket programming but I'm new to python so maybe this is a stupid question.

My software is doing its 3-way handshake as it should, and sends a packet with my information. But the thing is, it is not the right information it sends.

This is what I do:

```
MESSAGE = 0x13EC
s.send(MESSAGE)
```

I want the packet to contain the hex value 13EC, but it is sending it as a string right now, like "0x13EC". If I put it like this...

```
MESSAGE = '13EC'
```

...it's  just sending zeros.

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Bartel

BTW, I am using python 3.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

When writing `MESSAGE = 0x13EC` you're essentially creating a integer with the value of 5100. But the socket can't send integers (to my knowledge).

Instead what you want to do is send byte data in the shape of `\x13` and `\xEC`.
To do this, you can simply do:

```
MESSAGE = b'\x13\xEC'
s.send(MESSAGE)
```

And that should do it.
Or you can use [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to pack the data.

```
from struct import pack
VALUE = 0x13EC # 5100
MESSAGE = pack('H', VALUE) # 5100 -> b'\x13\xEC'
s.send(MESSAGE) # b'\x13\xEC'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, did the job for at least a big part! But I have just one orther problem now, if I put a lot of data in it, the bits are shifted or in any other way different than expected. Is there a limit on how much data you can put in it?

Comment: @gamma_spec by `it` you mean `pack()`? If so, yes you need to combine multiple `pack('H', 5100) + pack('Q', 5)` for instance.